# How to get exception message?

Tags: google-app-engine, exception

I use the following code currently:

```
from google.appengine.api.urlfetch import Error
try:
    # some code here
except Error, message:
    logging.error('exception - %s' % message)
```

But it will capture urlfetch errors only.
If I replace it with:

```
try:
    # some code here
except:
    logging.error('exception')
```

Then it captures all errors. But how can I get error message in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the generic Python Exception:

```
try:
    i = 6/0
except Exception as e:
    print( e )
```